# How can I install the imaplib library for Python on Fedora?

Tags: python

I want to use `imaplib` in Python on Fedora.  I tried `yum install imap` but got `Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit No package imap available. Error: Nothing to do`.  How do I install imaplib?

Answer (score 6):

[`imaplib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) is a built in package that comes with Python.  You don't need to install anything separately.  Even if you did, you'd more likely have to install a Python package with `pip` than a system package with `yum`.  Simply import the package and start coding.

```
import imaplib
```